# Google+ Sign In: How to obtain both the email and other profile information in one asynchronous call?

Tags: asynchronous, authentication, google-plus

I need to get the email, id, first name, and last name from Google+ in order to create an account for the user. In order to do that, all the examples that I've seen have said to do this:

```
    // Get the email
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function()
    {
        gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.email);
        })
    });

    // Get the id, first name, and last name
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function()
    {
        gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} ).execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.id);
            console.log(resp.name.givenName);
            console.log(resp.name.familyName);
        })
    });
```

However, there's a problem with this, since I want to be able to store the resp.email, resp.id, resp.name.givenName, resp.name.familyName in variables so that after those two calls I can use that info to create a user account. Since the execute() is an asynchronous call, I am unable to do that (at least with my knowledge). I figured the easiest solution would be to see if there was some way to get everything I wanted (email, id, last name, first name) all at once, so that I could do my user creation inside of the execute() function. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested you can call another function from in the execute anonymous function to
do further code......
or if you like to separate code a bit, store these variables in global var s and call yu app code function, or i might recommend using window.setTimeout(your_fn,1); 
calling your function asynchronously gives the browser some ui responsiveness.
There many different ways to code it.

Also note, [error "Access Not Configured.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872669/2791470)